# How to fix viz that is getting out of sync when I change browser tabs?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm using [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wW6X/) as a template, and I've noticed that when I change browser tabs and change back, the graph gets out of sync (the colored lines don't move but the x-axis shifts).

What can I add in d3 that will shift both the viz's lines AND time axis when I change browser tabs then change back to the viz tab?  Full code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Live Pressure Data</title>
    <style>
        svg {
            font: 12px sans-serif;
        }

        .line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: black;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .y.axis path {
            display: none;
        }

        .y.axis line {
            stroke: #777;
            stroke-dasharray: 2px,2px;
        }

        .grid .tick {
            stroke: lightgrey;
            opacity: 0.7;
        }

        .grid path {
            stroke-width: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <!--<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var n = 120;
        var nSensors = 4;
        var duration = 1000;

        var now = new Date(Date.now() - duration);
        // 1 x nSensors array of zeros
        var count = d3.range(nSensors).map(function () {
            return 0;
        });
        // nSensors x n array of zeros
        var data = count.map(function () {
            return d3.range(n).map(function () {
                return 0;
            });
        });

        var margin = { top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 20 };
        var width = 800 - margin.right - margin.left;
        var height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var x = d3.time.scale()
                       .domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration])
                       .range([0, width]);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0, 100])
                        .range([height, 0]);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
                         .interpolate("basis")
                         .x(function (d, i) { return x(now - (n - 1 - i) * duration); })
                         .y(function (d, i) { return y(d); });

        var color = d3.scale.category10();

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                    .attr("class", "lineChart")
                    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
           .attr("id", "clip")
           .append("rect")
           .attr("width", width)
           .attr("height", height);

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                          .scale(y)
                          .tickSize(width)
                          .orient("right")

        var gy = svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .call(yAxis)

        gy.selectAll("text")
          .attr("text-anchor", "end")
          .attr("x", 4)
          .attr("dy", -4)

        var xAxis = svg.append("g")
                       .attr("class", "x axis")
                       .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                       .call(x.axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

        var clipPath = svg.append("g")
                          .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

        var paths = clipPath.append("g")

        for (var series in data) {
            paths.append("path")
                 .attr("class", "line")
                 .data([data[series]])
                 .style("stroke", color(series))
        }

        // Live bar graph
        var barW = 300 - margin.left - margin.right;
        var barH = 190 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        var rectH = 28;

        var barX = d3.scale.linear()
                               .domain([0, 100])
                               .range([0, barW]);

        var barSvg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                       .attr("class", "barChart")
                       .attr("width", barW + margin.right + margin.left)
                       .attr("height", barH + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                       .append("g")
                       .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

        barSvg.selectAll("rect")
              .data(count)
              .enter().append("rect")
              .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * 38; })
              .attr("width", barX)
              .style("fill", function (d, i) { return color(i); })
              .attr("height", rectH);

        barSvg.selectAll("text")
              .data(count)
              .enter().append("text")
              .attr("x", 50)
              .attr("y", function (d, i) { return (i * 38) + 14 })
              .attr("dy", "0.35em")
              .attr("text-anchor", "end")
              .text(function (d) { return d + " psi" })

        barSvg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + barH + ")")
              .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(barX).orient("bottom"))

        // Live data
        //var socket = io.connect('');

        //socket.on('news', function (pressure) {
        //    oldCount = count;
        //    count = pressure.values;
        //})

        setInterval(function () {
            for (var series in count) {
                count[series] += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 5;
                count[series] = Math.min(Math.max(count[series], 0), 100);
            }
        }, 900);


        // Animate
        tick();

        function tick() {

            // update the domains
            now = new Date();
            x.domain([now - (n - 2) * duration, now - duration]);

            for (var series in data) {
                data[series].push(count[series]);
            }

            // slide the x-axis left
            xAxis.transition()
                 .duration(duration)
                 .ease("linear")
                 .call(x.axis);

            // redraw the line
            svg.selectAll(".line")
               .attr("d", line)

            // slide the line left
            paths.attr("transform", null)
                 .transition()
                 .duration(duration)
                 .ease("linear")
                 .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(now - (n - 1) * duration) + ")")
                 .each("end", tick);

            // pop the old data point off the front
            for (var series in data) {
                data[series].shift();
            }

            // bar animation
            barSvg.selectAll("rect")
                  .data(count)
                  .transition()
                  .duration(duration)
                  .attr("width", barX);

            barSvg.selectAll("text")
                  .data(count)
                  .text(function (d) { return Math.floor(d) + " psi" })
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transitions are trouncing each other.

If you look at the source code to the examples [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/), you'll notice this curious line in the tick function:

```
function tick() {
    transition = transition.each(function() {
    ...
```

According to [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions):

> If type is not specified, behaves similarly to selection.each:
>   immediately invokes the specified function for each element in the
>   current transition, passing in the current datum d and index i, with
>   the this context of the current DOM element. Any transitions created
>   within the scope of transition.each will inherit transition parameters
>   from the parent transition, including id, delay, duration and easing.
>   Thus, transitions created within a transition.each will not interrupt
>   the parent transition, similar to subtransitions.
>
> **The transition.each method can be used to chain transitions and apply
>   shared timing across a set of transitions.**

[bolding mine]

Applying this to your [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/esyDrULQG6HZTUz0X1TF?p=preview), seems to fix your issue.

Note, I had to change your `paths` variable.  After I wrapped up the transitions, it was no longer a smooth transition when contained in the outer `g` element.

Comment: I'm not understanding why my transitions are trouncing each other, but the viz looks perfect.  Thank you!